# VSCode plugin VSCode-PHP-Format not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I start using vscode less than a month. Please forgive me if this is a dump question.

- OS: OS X 10.11.3
- VSCode: 0.10.6
- Plugin: [VSCode-PHP-Format](https://github.com/kasik96/VSCode-PHP-Format) (download via git clone)
- Extension path: ~/.vscode/extensions/VSCode-PHP-Format

I restarted VSCode, open php files, but do not see "Format Code" on the right click menu.

Any idea how to debug this? Right now I don't even know if the plugin load correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tips from Tobiah Zarlez, I found the "Toggle Developer Tools" in VSCode.

It is shown in the console the plugin cannot find js-beautify.

**Solution**

Inside ~/.vscode/extensions/VSCode-PHP-Format, run

> npm install

It will pull in js-beautify. Then restart VSCode.

Comment: Great!

If you installed the plugin directly from the marketplace, there should be no need to run npm install (as it should automatically included any needed dependencies)

Comment: Actually, can you check if you see that plugin from the market place? I am not able to find it, that's why I download it manually. The author says it should be.

Comment: It is, I just checked. Updated three days ago.

Just open the command pallet, and enter "Extension Install", hit enter then enter "PHP" and it's one of the first results.

This solution is basically rebuilding the plugin from source code. Where as in theory you should get the prebuilt solution directly from the marketplace.

Comment: @TobiahZarlez yup, it is there now, lol. O well, at least learn something new :D

Answer (score 0):

I am on my phone and not able to double check to see if it is there, but I'd recommend installing from the visual studio marketplace to insure the plug in is installed correctly. You can do so by hitting CTRL+SHIFT+P and typing "install extension"

Beyond that, a quick glance at the code the plug in should be activated when you open a php file... but since this is a third party plugin, I can't speak to if it actually works or not.

(Again, on phone so can't test)

What you could do is modify the extension.js file to add a "`console.log ("hello world")`" to the activate function. Them check the log to see if the plug in is installed correctly.

I saw you weren't the only person to complain about the plug in not working though. If I were you, I would continue to try and contact the creator

Comment: Thx! Issue found. Missing js-beautify. Need to run npm install manually